# Alternative way to migrate to DevOps from old version of TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migration

According to Microsoft's [migration guide (p. 25)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274), the TFSMigrator tool that will migrate data to DevOps only supports the current version and 1 previous version of TFS which means migrating to the newest TFS version is integral in the process.

I'm using an old version of TFS which I wouldn't have too big an issue upgrading except the server it runs on is Windows Server 2008 which doesn't support anything past TFS 2012.

**Since all I need is the code repository as it sits today** (I don't care about work items, history, or anything else), is there an alternative method for migrating my code?

I'm okay with something semi-manual if necessary. I have about 30 projects to migrate so if I had to migrate project by project, that isn't a big deal. I'm just hoping not to have to recreate each project by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs).

The process is:

- Use git-tfs to turn the source TFVC repo into a local Git repo with all of the history preserved
- Use git-tfs to "check in" the Git repo to the target TFVC repo

A few caveats:

- It's going to be slow.
- It's not going to be a full-fidelity migration; you're going to lose the dates of the checkins and possibly the identity of the person who made the checkin in the target system.

An alternative is to spin up a non-production modern TFS environment, clone your team project collection, upgrade it on the non-prod instance, then use the migration tool. That's going to capture everything with full fidelity, and that official tool is the only option you have if you want full fidelity.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution for me. I don't need a full-fidelity migration by any stretch and I don't care if it's slow as long as I don't have to recreate each project by hand. I'm testing it out on one of the projects now and I'll accept your answer assuming it works for me.